# Lattice multiple keys

Tags: r, lattice

I have problems with the following code. I want to make a plot where I have a complex legend on top of the plot, but I'm getting this last blue point and I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
library(lattice)


xyplot(rnorm(10)~rnorm(10),
       key = list(
           text = list(c("Title", "A", "B", "C")),
           points = list(pch=c(NA, 16, 17, 18), col="Red"),

           text = list(c("Title", "A", "B", "C", "D")),
           points = list(pch=c(NA, 16, 17, 18, 15), col="Green"),

           text = list(c("Title", "A", "B")),
           points = list(pch=c(NA, 16, 17), col="Blue")))
```

[image]

Comment: If you add an `NA` at the end of the `pch` vector in your last `points` `list` the extra blue goes away. I can't figure out why it is there to begin with. However, if you eliminate the middle (green) part of the key the point goes away as well. Odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether there is "replication" of the arguments to the length of the longest argument maximum is governed by the `rep` argument which defaults to TRUE:

```
xyplot(rnorm(10)~rnorm(10),
       key = list(rep=FALSE,
           text = list(c("Title", "A", "B", "C")),
           points = list(pch=c(NA, 16, 17, 18), col="Red"),

           text = list(c("Title", "A", "B", "C", "D")),
           points = list(pch=c(NA, 16, 17, 18, 15), col="Green"),

           text = list(c("Title", "A", "B")),
           points = list(pch=c(NA, 16, 17), col="Blue")))
```

No extra dot.... For the first one the NA in position 1 gets re-used at position 5 and there is no problem.

Comment: Not in a million years would have guessed :)

Comment: Guessing doesn't work very well in either lattice or ggplot2. I didn't know the answer until I read the `xyplot` help page. .... for about the 50th time. At least lattice is documented in its help pages. I can never find the answers in the ggplot help pages.